# Async/Await not working properly with map function ionic 4,typescript

Tags: typescript, angular7, ionic4

As I have mentioned in the title I have a method which contains map function.

I am using ionic 4.

```
 async searchedData(data){
      if(this.searchedItems.length == 0){
        this.clearfilter()
      }
      if(data == "cleardata"){
        this.searchedItems = [];
      }
       else{
       //after searching
       console.log(data)     
      await data.map(async x=>{
        x["file_type"] =x.resource_name.substring(x.resource_name.lastIndexOf('.')+1)
        user.forEach(element => {
          if(x["user_id"] == element.id){
                return x["userobj"] = element;
              }
          });
        x["socialIcons"] = this.socialIcons;
        x["user_reaction"] = await this.getCreativeReactions(x)
        console.log(x["user_reaction"]) 
        return x;
      }),

        this.searchedItems = this.searchedItems.concat(data);
      }
    }
```

The problem is with this line :

```
x["user_reaction"] = await this.getCreativeReactions(x) 
 console.log(x["user_reaction"])
```

`getCreativeReactions` Code is shown below

```
getCreativeReactions(x:any){
     this.creativeServices.getCreativeReactions1(x["id"],x["userobj"]["id"]).pipe(map(res1=>res1.json())).subscribe(res1=>{
          x["user_reaction"] = res1;
          x["user_reaction"].forEach(element=>{
            switch(element["latestReaction"]){
             case 'like' :{
              x["socialIcons"][0]["color"] = "danger" 
              x["socialIcons"][0]["operation"] = "cancellike"
              break;
             } 
             case "unlike":{
              x["socialIcons"][1]["color"] = "danger" 
              x["socialIcons"][1]["operation"] = "cancelunlike"
              break;  
             }
             case "cancellike":{
             x["socialIcons"][0]["color"] = "default" 
             x["socialIcons"][0]["operation"] = "like"
              break;
             }
             case "cancelunlike":{
             x["socialIcons"][1]["color"] = "default" 
             x["socialIcons"][1]["operation"] = "unlike"
              break;
             }
            }
          })
          return x["user_reaction"]
        })

      }
```

I have a method getCreative reactions which returns an array of objects. But the problem is that though await is prefixed as shown above console.log() executes first and then method is called.Hence i get x["user_reaction"] as undefined.

Am  i going wrong with async/await syntax with map function??

Comment: Can you post the code for the `getCreativeReactions` function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added getCreativeReactions code as well.

Comment: instead of `return x["user_reaction"]`, could you try `resolve(x["user_reaction"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your `getCreativeReactions` method return a Promise with resolve

Like this

```
getCreativeReactions(x: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.creativeServices.getCreativeReactions1(x["id"], x["userobj"]["id"]).pipe(map(res1 => res1.json())).subscribe(res1 => {
            x["user_reaction"] = res1;
            x["user_reaction"].forEach(element => {
                switch (element["latestReaction"]) {
                    case 'like': {
                        x["socialIcons"][0]["color"] = "danger"
                        x["socialIcons"][0]["operation"] = "cancellike"
                        break;
                    }
                    case "unlike": {
                        x["socialIcons"][1]["color"] = "danger"
                        x["socialIcons"][1]["operation"] = "cancelunlike"
                        break;
                    }
                    case "cancellike": {
                        x["socialIcons"][0]["color"] = "default"
                        x["socialIcons"][0]["operation"] = "like"
                        break;
                    }
                    case "cancelunlike": {
                        x["socialIcons"][1]["color"] = "default"
                        x["socialIcons"][1]["operation"] = "unlike"
                        break;
                    }
                }
            })
            resolve(x["user_reaction"]); // here we return the awaited value
        })
    });
}
```